# Download option is not working in iOS devices

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

We have developed a website in HTML and PHP is used for dynamic functionalities.

There is one section in the website where there is a download option. We have used below code, onclick of anchor tag PDF file is getting downloaded. It is working fine in desktops and android phones but not in apple devices. Please help in getting this issue resolved.

```
<div class="download-content-wrapper">
    <h3>Download Our Full Menu Here</h3>
    <a class="btn btn-download" href="skini.pdf">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its look like you are open PDF not download.

Comment: Have you tried it in safari ?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS devices, PDF files are opened in the iBooks app. Try opening it and seeing if it is set up. iOS devices don't download stuff like Androids and PCs, you can only get certain files on your iOS device from the internet like PDFs, Images. No videos and many other things. Either you don't have iBooks set up or you don't have iBooks at all.